# Has anyone here worked on KOFAX-SharePoint 2007 integration?

Tags: sharepoint, ecm, kofax

We want to be able to advance our business by utilizing both of the power of KOFAX and SharePoint 2007. Any pointers Development-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We looked into doing something like this a couple of years ago. We were thinking of having printed documents scanned in, converted with OCR, and organized digitally in a type of repository.

We actually did an analysis of OCR tools and repository / collaboration tools and which would be the easiest to integrate. We checked out Kofax, OCR for AnyDoc, and a couple of others on the OCR side, and SharePoint WSS, SharePoint MOSS, Hyland OnBase, SAP Collaboration Manager, and Documentum on the repository / collaboration side.

Your idea is good, and there are variants of it in use in banking and other industries. As for the integration, in my experience if you're using SharePoint, it should be pretty easy with Kofax if you leverage the API's on both sides and get creative with simple web parts and iFrames.

KA

Answer (score 0):

We have done it by building a custom release script from Kofax.

Key question is how much flexibility to you want in the integration for expanding in the future.  It is easy to build a one-off release script that handles a single document library or list.  It is a lot more to build something that is configurable.

OnBase is a nice option if you are looking for workflow and other ECM benefits.  You can scan to OnBase and then OnBase will push links directly into a library or list in SP automatically.

You also need to understand that searching and viewing of a high-volume of document images in SP can be cumbersome without some other tools.

E-mail me at sales@imagesoftinc.com if you'd like to discuss.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

PSIGEN makes a great onramp for SharePoint

[Scanning and Capture for SharePoint](http://www.psigen.com/sharepoint/sharepoint_scanning_capture_imaging.aspx)